# How can I add more languages to CentOs 8 and 7 using CLI

Tags: centos, language

How can I add more languages to CentOs 8 and 7 using CLI.

I tried different options:

1. install "yum groupinstall "Chinese Support"", I don't have it as group
2. Change language settings, returns back to English.

The language is not available in the OS. Using "locale" only English variations appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the "fonts" package by -

```
yum groupinstall "fonts"
```

Verify if the group "Chinese Support" is installed using -

```
yum groupinfo "Chinese Support"
```

Comment: fonts is not found as a group.

Comment: Can you supply the full error/warning?

Comment: Can you run `yum list langpacks-* | grep zh` and see if zh locale is supported?

Answer (score 0):

On centos 8:

To set locale use:

```
sudo localectl set-locale LANG=zh_CN.utf8
```

Additional step to set chinese locale:

edit you bash profile:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

add the following line:

```
source /etc/locale.conf
```

Then reboot.

RHEL: [1.3.2. Configuring the system locale](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/getting-started-with-system-administration_configuring-basic-system-settings#configuring-the-system-locale_changing-basic-environment-settings)